# Custom Feedback form in magento 2

Tags: theme, magento2.2, footer-links

How to create a footer link in custom theme and how to set path to that link ?

I have created custom feedback module which contains form for feedback.

Now I need to set link in custom theme and want to set path for the link.

The path should refer from my feedback module** Please help me

**=> Custom Module:layout file**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Sample
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="X_Y::form.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

form.phtml

```
<div>
    <a id="feedback">Feedback</a>
.....
....
....
</div>
```

**While clicking link it will show a popup. So here I have mentioned id, Now I have declared my link in custom theme, But How do I specify this id in link**

Comment: If you have any query then feel free to ask me.

Comment: If I added this in my custom theme then what is the need of my layout file in custom module

Comment: You need to add footer links so you must need to add in custom theme. In custom module, layout file used for your controller action. Do not remove that file from custom module.

Comment: @Rohan Hapani  Please the the updated post and solve my issue

Comment: This answer already working. Where's problem occured?

Comment: You just add your form.phtml file path at url-key-of-your-page. No need of use anchor tag and all.

Comment: I know that there is no use of using anchor tag, But the id which is specified in anchor tag is used in my js file, while clicking the link it would show a form as a popup modal

Answer (score 1):

To add new links to footer links, use this code in `<Vendor>\theme>\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="your-link-name">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Title</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path-of-your-page</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Shall I add default.xml file in my custom module instead of custom theme

Comment: No. You can add it in your custom theme.

Comment: If I added this link in custom theme then What is the need of my layout file (Which consists only a link) in custom module ?? Am I need to remove layout file ?

Comment: No. Then you can add it in your custom module. In this case no need to use custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/CustomName/customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
<body>

<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-page">
<arguments>
<argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Title of your page</argument>
<argument name="path" xsi:type="string">url-key-of-your-page</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>

</body>
</page>
```

Create your `default.xml` on this above path and try it. It will works.